# How can I remap list of numbers by changing its domain to a new target domain?

Tags: python, math, remap

I have these numbers:

1. 0.477486
2. 0.627644
3. 0.763021
4. 0.857888
5. 0.892062
6. 0.857888
7. 0.763021
8. 0.627644
9. 0.477486

   and I want to remap them to a new target domain for example 0 to 10 instead of 0.477486 to 0.892062.

Comment: Can you explain how the remapping works?

Comment: Subtract `0.477486` from each number then multiply by `10 / (0.892062 - 0.477486)`

Comment: @Selcuk thanks for your reply. but it will be divided by 0 in case of 10 / (0.477486- 0.477486)

Comment: @Barmar I want to increase the difference between these numbers so I want to change there domain.

Comment: @dai You are misreading my formula. `10 / (0.892062 - 0.477486)` is a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
>>> l = [0.477486, 0.627644, 0.763021, 0.857888, 0.892062,
         0.857888, 0.763021, 0.627644, 0.477486]
>>> print([(i - min(l)) * 10 / (max(l) - min(l)) for i in l])
```

This should print

```
[0.0, 3.6219655744664423, 6.887398209254755, 9.17568793176643, 10.0, 9.17568793176643, 6.887398209254755, 3.6219655744664423, 0.0]
```

Comment: Yes sorry I misread.Thank you!